# Selecting a Checkbox and deleting a data grid row in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, checkbox, datagrid, row

I am trying to implement the following :

1. First column of datagrid has a checkbox.
2. Select checkboxes, and then delete the datagrid column.
3. Dynamically, add checkbox when row is added dynamically.
4. Do not show check box if now data in row.

Can someone give some guidance ?

Comment: "2> Select checkboxes, and then delete the datagrid column" Do you mean "Delete datagrid row"?

Comment: Ya..delete row , not column. Sorry.

Comment: Strange. It works for me. Sometimes the change event for the checkbox does not get processed until you click on another row of the datagrid

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you want to delete a row and not a column. The following works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                layout="vertical">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.IndexChangedEvent;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            [Bindable]
            private var ac:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection([{name: "John", shouldDelete: true}, {name: "Joe", shouldDelete: false}, {name: "Jill", shouldDelete: false}])


            private function deleteRows()
            {
                for each (var row:Object in ac)
                {
                    if (row.shouldDelete == true)
                    {
                        var i:int=ac.getItemIndex(row);
                        ac.removeItemAt(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:VBox>
        <mx:DataGrid id="dg"
                     dataProvider="{ac}">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name">

                </mx:DataGridColumn>
                <mx:DataGridColumn id="col2"
                                   editorDataField="selected"
                                   rendererIsEditor="true"
                                   dataField="data.shouldDelete">
                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                        <mx:Component>
                            <mx:CheckBox label="Test"
                                         selected="{data.shouldDelete}"
                                         change="data.shouldDelete=selected"/>
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer>
                </mx:DataGridColumn>

            </mx:columns>

        </mx:DataGrid>
        <mx:Button label="delete"
                   id="deleteBtn"
                   click="deleteRows()"/>

    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: The delete is not deleting the row. Nothing happensa apart from checkbox getting selected. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

In itemdatabound u should give enabled as false in particular cell....